# What does Rome, Conquerors & Titans have in common?

Tags: greek, roman, mythohistory, history, titans

I think something with Heracles, but I am unsure.

Comment: they all relate to each other in multiple ways, and the context would be very important. I'd start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titans_(mythology) and see what makes sense. The Titans were the first gods, overthrown (conquered?) by the later gods (who are sometimes also called Titans...). Tiberinus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiberinus_(god) who's parents were Titans, is a river god of the Tiber, who is said to have protected Romulus and Remus (the founders of Rome). Exactly which conquest is involved is guesswork.

Comment: The Romans were obviously [conquerors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Empire); as for the titans, well, [Denzel Washington](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9VDrVs3CJE&t=42) did a better job at explaining it than I ever will.

Comment: @DWKraus The titans where not the first gods. The titans overthrew the primordial gods and then get overthrown by the Olympians. Ouranos prophesied the fall of the Titans and the punishments they would suffer for their crimes, a prophecy brought to fruition by Zeus and others who deposed and cast them into the pit of Tartaros.

Comment: Simply asking your manager what these things have in common is not possible? Since the answer to the question depends on what your manager thinks they have in common. If this commonality is based on a wrong interpretation by your manager we can never make an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Heracles supposedly conquered Rome and freed a Titan.

Hesiod's *Theogony* and Aeschylus' *Prometheus Unbound* both tell that Heracles shot and killed the eagle that tortured Prometheus (which was his punishment by Zeus for stealing fire from the gods and giving it to mortals). Heracles freed the Titan from his chains and his torments. Prometheus then made predictions regarding further deeds of Heracles.

In ancient Roman religion and myth, Hercules was venerated as a divinized hero and incorporated into the legends of Rome's founding.

Comment: Thank you, I knew there was something like this, but couldn't remember the exact details.

Comment: That could be, but I don't remember Heracles conquering Rome. Do you have a link for that please?

Comment: IIRC it was in one of the 12 works of Hercules where he defeats a fire-breathing giant that occupied the Palatine Hill, the center fill of the Seven Hills of Rome,

Comment: @gsamaras This may have been a side-quest for Hercules https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules_in_ancient_Rome He drove Geryon's cattle over the Aventine hill and battled the giant Cacus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacus

Comment: Thanks a lot @DWKraus for commenting on my question, despite its negative score.:)

Comment: @gsamaras don't stress too much about negative scores around here. The history site is even worse. Mostly it's because people expect evidence of research, but this question would be hard to piece together the disparate elements.

Comment: Hello Codosaur, this question keeps getting downvoted, strongly signaling me that my post is poor quality for this site. I tried deleting it, but I cannot, unless you delete your, very good, answer.